# extract data immediately after numeric value in a cell in google sheets

Tags: regex, google-sheets, extract, spreadsheet

I have cells containing data in google spreadsheet as quantity of some entity and I wish to extract only that string which is after the quantity value (number).

Example, If my data is :

```
learn 10 functions
Watch 3 YT tutorial videos
complete 10 charts
```

I want the result as :

```
functions
YT tutorial videos
charts
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A, "\d+ (.+)")))
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that you don't have multiple numbers occurrences in the text, you can use this regex.

```
(?<=\d\s).+$
```

This regex will match all characters after a number followed by a single space to the end of the line.

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/spjqWT/1)